# Check Contains into an int array for null property

Tags: c#, linq

I have in int[] and want to check that particular property from list exist into an array or not. Here is my class of property,

```
public class WaitingLists
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public Int32 GameTableId { get; set; }
        public Int32 WaitingListTypeId { get; set; }
        **public Int32 ? StakeBuyInId { get; set; }**
    }
```

Then I want to check that StakeBuyInId exists in my list.

Here is a code for Linq,

```
public GameListItem[] GetMyWaitingList(Guid UserId, int[] WaitingListTypeIds, int[] StakeBuyInIds)
        {
            ProviderDB db = new ProviderDB();

            List<GameListItem> objtempGameListItem = new List<GameListItem>();

            List<GameTables> objGameTablesList = new List<GameTables>();

            var objWaitingListUser = db.WaitingLists.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(UserId));
            if (WaitingListTypeIds != null)
            {
                objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(x => WaitingListTypeIds.Contains(x.WaitingListTypeId));
            }
            **if (StakeBuyInIds != null)
            {
                objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(x => x.StakeBuyInId != null ? StakeBuyInIds.Contains(x.StakeBuyInId) : false);
            }**
            return objtempGameListItem.ToArray();
        }
```

But it is showing me an error that Contains does not allow `int?`. It only overloads `int`.

How do you use Contains for null property using linq? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
StakeBuyInIds.Contains((Int32)x.StakeBuyInId)
```

OR

```
objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(x => 
                 x.StakeBuyInId.HasValue  && 
                 StakeBuyInIds.Contains((Int32)x.StakeBuyInId));
```

Comment: or better `StakeBuyInIds.Contains(x.StakeBuyInId.GetValueOrDefault())` OR `objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(x => StakeBuyInIds.Contains( x.StakeBuyInId.GetValueOrDefault() );`

Comment: it did not work   var MatchedGroup = query.Where(x => x.ContentGroupID == cgItem.GroupID 
                    && x.IsInGrpAndPublish != null && x.IsInGrpAndPublish == 1 
                    && publishedSitesFilter.Contains(x.SiteID.GetValueOrDefault()) ).Select(
                    x => new ContentGroupEntity
                    {
                        GroupID = cgItem.GroupID,
                        GroupName = cgItem.GroupName
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 2):

you could also create an extension

```
    public static bool Contains<T>(this IList<T> container, T? content)
    {
        if (content.HasValue)
            if (container.Contains(content.Value))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

and your query would looks like this

```
objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(x => StakeBuyInIds.Contains(x.StakeBuyInId))
```

instead of

```
objWaitingListUser = objWaitingListUser.Where(x => x.StakeBuyInId != null 
                                                   ? StakeBuyInIds.Contains(x.StakeBuyInId) 
                                                   : false);
```

Comment: Works well but requires the following after the method signature: `where T : struct, IComparable`